# Is it appropriate to rely on Meteor.settings in package autotest?

Tags: meteor, tinytest

My package relies on Meteor.settings, a certain property that has to contain certain values. Whether it is appropriate to check for it in the auto test of the package? Depending on settings, the package may or may not throw `Meteor.Error`s and return various results.